# Unable to set MAX_LINE_LENGTH in PyDev/Luna

Tags: eclipse, pydev, eclipse-luna

In the previous version of Eclipse (Kepler) I could go the Window|Preferences|PyDdev|Editor|Code Analysis|pep8.py and see where the script that was was installed. I could then go into that script, modify the MAX_LINE_LENGTH value from 79 to 110, and the code analysis wouldn't complain about a line being too long until it was over 110 characters.

Since upgrading to Luna, the pep8.py tab on the code analysis preferences no longer points to the pep8.py script being used.

I searched for all copies of pep8.py in my Eclipse and Python installations, modified all of them to a MAX_LINE_LENGTH of 110, but PyDev/Eclipse continue to try to force a max line length of 79.

Any tips on how to accomplish this in Luna?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the location of the file is no longer exposed as describe above on the Preferences dialog, I was able to find this file, modify the MAX_LINE_LENGTH value, restarted Eclipse and all was well. Be sure to select the correct folder that corresponds to your current PyDev version.

/Progarm Files (x86)/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_*3.7.1.201409021729*/pysrc/third_party/pep8.py

Note that one of my fellow developers was able to accomplish this and in the process I noticed (via the path to the file) that his version of PyDev was slightly later than mine was - my attempt at accomplishing this was unsuccessful until I updated PyDev to the current version (3.7.1). I have no idea what effect the version of PyDev had, so something else may have been interfering with my change to the MAX_LINE_LENGTH from taking effect.